# How can I reuse a box that I have moved the value out of?

Tags: rust, move-semantics, boxing, ownership-semantics

I have some non-copyable type and a function that consumes and (maybe) produces it:

```
type Foo = Vec<u8>;

fn quux(_: Foo) -> Option<Foo> {
    Some(Vec::new())
}
```

Now consider a type that is somehow conceptually very similar to `Box`:

```
struct NotBox<T> {
    contents: T
}
```

We can write a function that temporarily moves out contents of the `NotBox` and puts something back in before returning it:

```
fn bar(mut notbox: NotBox<Foo>) -> Option<NotBox<Foo>> {
    let foo = notbox.contents; // now `notbox` is "empty"
    match quux(foo) {
        Some(new_foo) => {
            notbox.contents = new_foo; // we put something back in
            Some(notbox)
        }
        None => None
    }
}
```

I want to write an analogous function that works with `Box`es but the compiler does not like it:

```
fn baz(mut abox: Box<Foo>) -> Option<Box<Foo>> {
    let foo = *abox; // now `abox` is "empty"
    match quux(foo) {
        Some(new_foo) => {
            *abox = new_foo; // error: use of moved value: `abox`
            Some(abox)
        }
        None => None
    }
}
```

I could return `Some(Box::new(new_foo))` instead but that performs unnecessary allocation - I already have some memory at my disposal! Is it possible to avoid that?

I would also like to get rid of the `match` statements but again the compiler is not happy with it (even for the `NotBox` version):

```
fn bar(mut notbox: NotBox<Foo>) -> Option<NotBox<Foo>> {
    let foo = notbox.contents;
    quux(foo).map(|new_foo| {
        notbox.contents = new_foo; // error: capture of partially moved value: `notbox`
        notbox
    })
}
```

Is it possible to work around that?

Comment: You seem to be asking more than one question here.  The match vs map one looks like it should be move to a new question.

Comment: I was going to answer the first part but realised that I don't yet understand how moving out of `Box<T>` works; it doesn't seem to be related to `Deref` or `DerefMut` traits.  So looking forward to a good answer too!

Comment: @ChrisEmerson The match part was something that popped up when I was trying to create the minimal example of my problem so I haven't put much research into it. I just thought that this is probably related to the general question and the fact that I don't get how "partial" moves work so I left it here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So, moving out of a `Box` is a special case... now what?

The `std::mem` module presents a number of safe functions to move values around, without poking holes (!) into the memory safety of Rust. Of interest here are `swap` and [`replace`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.replace.html):

> ```
> pub fn replace<T>(dest: &mut T, src: T) -> T
> ```

Which we can use like so:

```
fn baz(mut abox: Box<Foo>) -> Option<Box<Foo>> {
    let foo = std::mem::replace(&mut *abox, Foo::default());

    match quux(foo) {
        Some(new_foo) => {
            *abox = new_foo;
            Some(abox)
        }
        None => None
    }
}
```

It also helps in the `map` case, because it does not borrow the `Box`:

```
fn baz(mut abox: Box<Foo>) -> Option<Box<Foo>> {
    let foo = std::mem::replace(&mut *abox, Foo::default());

    quux(foo).map(|new_foo| { *abox = new_foo; abox })
}
```

Comment: The downside is that `Foo:default()` needs to exist and hopefully be cheap to execute. If neither is true, then the suggestion to switch to a `Box<Option<Foo>>` would be useful as then you can call `take` and `None` is the cheap-to-create default.

Comment: @Shepmaster: Agreed :) However I'd rather stick to the presented scenario and only elaborate if the OP has more specific concerns, otherwise I am afraid the answer might drown anyone attempting to read it.

Answer (score 5):

Moving out of boxes is special-cased in the compiler. You can move something out of them, but you can't move something back in, because the act of moving out also deallocates. You can do something silly with `std::ptr::write`, `std::ptr::read`, and `std::ptr::replace`, but it's hard to get it right, because *something* valid should be inside a `Box` when it is dropped. I would recommend just accepting the allocation, or switching to a `Box<Option<Foo>>` instead.

Comment: My biggest annoyance with Rust is that some details like this apparently aren't documented outside of discussion threads or sometimes in passing in RFCs.  :-(  FWIW, it's mentioned [in this postponed RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/178) .

Comment: @ChrisEmerson i think in this case, the special casing of `Box` is something that wants to be removed and transformed to the proposed `DerefMove` trait. Don't want to show too much dirty laundry and have it be widley internalized if it can become more reusable and generic. Note that the [RFC has been restarted](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1646) as well.

Answer (score 0):

> We can write a function that temporarily moves out contents of the NotBox and puts something back in before returning it

That's because you can partially move out from the struct that you take by value. It behaves as if all fields were separate variables. That is not possible though if the struct implements `Drop`, because `drop` needs the whole struct to be valid, always (in case of panic).

As for providing workaround, you haven't provided enough information – especially, why `baz` needs to take `Box` as an argument and why `quux` can't? Which functions are yours and which are part of an API you can't change? What is the real type of `Foo`? Is it big?

The best workaround would be not to use `Box` at all.