# How to move a field whose type does not implement Default from a struct which implements Drop?

Tags: rust

There are some [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31307680/1403530) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38397163/1403530), but [the](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31308299/1403530) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38400931/1403530) require the field to implement [`Default`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/default/trait.Default.html) or some way to initialize another value with the type of the field.

---

We have a `Node` which has a `value` of type `T`:

```
struct Node<T> {
    value: T,
    next: Option<Box<T>>
}
```

It has a method which moves `value` from a `Node`:

```
impl<T> Node<T> {
    fn value(self) -> T {
        self.value
    }
}
```

The code above compiles. But if we implement `Drop` for `Node`:

```
impl<T> Drop for Node<T> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {}
}
```

Then we will get a compile error:

```
error[E0509]: cannot move out of type `Node<T>`, which implements the `Drop` trait
   |         self.value
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^
   |         |
   |         cannot move out of here
   |         move occurs because `self.value` has type `T`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

I guess it doesn't compile because if we implement a custom `Drop`, we need to make sure not to drop `value` field if the drop happens at the end of `value` method's block. However, we cannot check that; and even if we could, the compiler cannot statically check that we do it.

One way to workaround this is to store `value` field as `Option<T>`. But suppose that we don't want to use `Option` for some reasons (the overhead, etc),

What else can we do to have both a custom `Drop` and a `value` method that moves `value` field?

I guess we have to use some `unsafe` approach and that's fine.

---

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=28b0c5902a95e50edc47d3b8963f2043)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to move one field out of a struct that implements Drop trait?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31307680/how-to-move-one-field-out-of-a-struct-that-implements-drop-trait)

Comment: That not because the answer doesn't fit you that make your question not a duplicate.

Comment: @Stargateur That question I have mentioned at the top of the question and I have explained why it isn't applicable here.

Comment: Again, the question is totally a duplicate, answer that require a default value are irrelevant. There is no way to trick the compiler to do what you want no matter the amount of unsafe you will use. Either use Option, use default, Clone the value, not implement Drop.

Comment: That's not irrelevant. I also think there _might_ be no way to do it _safely_, but I might be wrong (i.e. there actually is), hence the question. And it's also okay if the approach is unsafe.

Comment: See https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/destructuring-structs-which-implement-drop/137

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a way to do this without using `unsafe` (though someone else might), but here is a way to do it using `unsafe`:

```
use std::{ptr, mem};

impl<T> Node<T> {
    fn value(mut self) -> T {
        unsafe {
            let v: T = ptr::read(&self.value);
            ptr::drop_in_place(&mut self.next);
            mem::forget(self);
            v
        }
    }
}
```

We use `ptr::read` to move the desired value out. We then need to use `mem::forget` on the `Node` to make sure its `drop` method is not called (since otherwise `value` could be dropped twice and cause undefined behavior). To prevent the `next` member from leaking, we use `ptr::drop_in_place` to run its `drop` method.

It's interesting to me that this safe code does not work:

```
impl<T> Node<T> {
    fn value(self) -> T {
        match self {
            Node {value, next: _} => value
        }
    }
}
```

It gives that same error:

> error[E0509]: cannot move out of type `Node<T>`, which implements the
> `Drop` trait

I would have expected that with the `match` expression taking ownership of all of `self` and breaking it into its components, there would be no way for `drop` to be called on `self` and hence no reason for the compiler to complain. But apparently it does not work this way.