# Is memory leaked when a Box is dereferenced?

Tags: rust, memory-leaks, smart-pointers, dereference, box

I've recognized that when moving a dereferenced `Box` with `*Box::new(_)`, it doesn't call `Deref::deref` nor `DerefMut::deref_mut`; it really moves the value, which means `*Box::new(_)` has ownership, not a dereference of a reference.

An example:

```rust
let a = Box::new(String::from("hello");

let b = *a;
```

I've learned that `Box` is an extraordinary struct, so that in the case of data move, it actually dereferences like a reference (without `Deref` trait).

1. During the movement, what happens to the memory allocated by `Box` in the heap? Is it freed? Is it replaced with bunch of zeroes? Does it remains only not having any way of being accessed?

   I know that memory allocated by `String::from` will be freed when `b` drops. I'm not curious of data `str type hello`, I'm curious of memory which would has a size of `size of String`.
2. How can I explicitly dereference a `Box` without `Deref` trait? When I try it, it automatically borrows `Box` by calling `Deref::deref`.

   ```
   let a = Box::new(String::from("hello"));

   fn test(i: &String) {}

   test(&(*a));
   ```

   The compiler infers that there's no need for moving `*a`, so it seems like it dereferences by the trait, not directly.

   This case successfully consumes the box and the string:

   ```rust
   let a = Box::new(String::from("hello"));

   fn test(i: String) {}

   test(*a)
   ```

Comment: It's hard to answer multiple questions made in one post. Please separate them into multiple questions so that we can help you better and so that your questions will help others in the future that have one of the same questions as you!

Comment: Your question might be answered by the answers of [How can I reuse a box that I have moved the value out of?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38397163/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I've learned that Box is an extraordinary struct, so that in the case of data move, it actually dereferences like a reference (without Deref trait).

It doesn't, which is rather the point. [`Box` alone has access to an intrinsic "deref move" feature](https://manishearth.github.io/blog/2017/01/10/rust-tidbits-box-is-special/) which is [not actually formalised or otherwise available](https://github.com/alercah/rfcs/blob/deref-move/text/0000-deref-move.md).

> During the movement, what happens to the memory allocated by Box in the heap? Is it freed?

Yes.

> How can I explicitly dereference a Box without Deref trait?

By using `*`.

> test(&(*a));

The parens do nothing useful here, this just reborrows the pointee.

Replacing the parens by *braces* would [force moving the dereferenced value](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/expressions/block-expr.html).

Comment: Wow! It's now clear. Thank you!! Making it expression seems the best! ( It was just for my curiosity, though lol)